# Can't update an extjs gridpanel's toolbar

Tags: javascript, extjs

In extjs 2, I have a function, which returns one of two arrays, which is used on page load for

```
// onload
var grid = Ext.grid.GridPanel({
  ...
  tbar : getBar()
  ...
});

...

// later in a function
grid.tbar = getBar()
grid.getView().refresh()
```

Is there something else I need to refresh?  Or is there a fundamental difference in setting the tbar at load time--`tbar : getBar()`--versus setting it later--`grid.tbar = getBar()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `doLayout` isn't available in 2.2, I was recommended to just add all possible buttons/widgets to the toolbar and show/hide them individually.  This seems to work suitably.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get your grid's toolbar you're better using

`grid.getTopToolbar();`

and then to refresh the layout of the toolbar you need to use

`grid.getTopToolbar().doLayout();`

The `doLayout();` will tell ExtJS to redraw the toolbar's layout with any changes that you have made to it.

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm running 2.2.  Calling doLayout() on my toolbar gives me a "toolbar.doLayout is not a function".  Is this specific to 2.2 and you're referring to older/newer functionality?